# Loading an url with jquery load() with attached id value after # simply just stripped out from after hash

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5

I am trying to load a specific portion of an article with using of jquery load() function when a tab is clicked. The tab is inside an article and trying to show another article within the first article from where the tab is being clicked. The jquery code I have put inside the template.php of choosen template. The main problem is that when I click nothing is comming inside the first article under the tab. I am using joomla2.5.11 version. Please give some suggestion.The jquery code what I am trying is shown below:

```
    $(function(){

            $("h3.menuheader").click(function(){
                $(".active-tab").removeClass("active-tab");
                $(this).addClass("active-tab");
                $(".tabcontent-ul").slideUp();
                $(".tabcontent").load("http://www.mpsinfoservices.com/projects/teamzstudio/web-application-development#link1",function(){
                    $(".tabcontent").slideToggle();
                });
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you've provided enough to diagnose this issue. But perhaps I can help with how I would diagnose.

To start with, try this instead:

```
// http://www.mpsinfoservices.com/projects/teamzstudio/web-application-development#link1
$(".tabcontent").load("http://www.google.co.uk",function(){
  $(".tabcontent").slideToggle();
});
```

Then open up your developer tools and see if a call is being made to load that data.

If it is, then you need to consider that it might be loading the data and putting it in another element you can't see.

So to test, create a new container on the page near your footer, which you know will be visible with a specific `#ID` like `<div id="testID"></div>` and load into that. Once that is working, look to confirm your `.tabcontent` element is the one you want using something like `console.log()`.

Comment: I just checked with the relative path means /projects/teamzstudio/web-application-development#link1. The whole article page is comming but I need only to load the portion of the article content which is wrapped with a div, has an id link1. The whole page is comming because #link1 is surprisingly vanish from that url.Any idea why it is happening inspite of putting #link1

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I believe load doesn't support the hash. But looking here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-content-from-hash-in-url it looks like there is a jquery pluggin to achieve what you need.